# Correct method to move wordpress from 'localhost' to and IP address/domain setup

Tags: wordpress, web, dns, hosting

I'm a bit confused on how to do the above. I setup wordpress and developed my website all using 'localhost' all of the time

So all SQL statements, links, everything all use 'localhost'

Now I'm looking at moving it to a hosting solution I am a bit stuck as I've copied the files over, created the database etc but I couldn't see any styling at first (this has now changed), but I don't think I've done it the correct way as all links within my website pages, the home button on the menu, all pictures used in my themes picture slider have all had to be changed manually to the domain name, otherwise it tries to look for files and pages on 'localhost', which obviously aren't there as localhost (for the user) is just the users PC now rather than the server.

Surely there must be a better way of doing it so you don't need to change all the links, I could imagine this being a massive task on a big website

So what I've done overall is copy files, create database, changed WP Address URL in the options to the local IP of the server it is hosted on, changed Site Address URL to the domain name URL (which is forwarded to the local IP of the server, using port forwarding)

The reason I set the local IP of the server as the WP Address URL is because that allowed the SQL statements to work without being re-written

Hope someone can help and tell me the proper way to do this :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving wordpress site is a hectic task if done manually and for it to work perfect, you needs to do a lot of changes manually. But the Good thing about wordpress is it's plugins. There are some very good plugins for **Wordpress Sites Migration** that take care of all this on plugin end, doing all hectic tasks itself.

Now let me mention here 2 plugins for this:

***1 - Wordpress Duplicator***

Duplicator is a free plugin and available on wordpress.org plugins repository 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ 
You just need to install plugin, activate it and then a "DUPLICATOR" Menu item will appear in admin. From there, you create a package of your website. (You can install Duplicator on localhost and then create package from there). After that, for the website where you want to migrate website to, just upload or FTP the package there. And alongwith that package, upload a simple **script file**, that's provided by Duplicator. Run the script file, and just enter new website URL, new database details, - it will automatically detect the package, install the website and you'll see all the links are updated, and website is Live on new URL

***2 - BackupBuddy***

Backupbuddy is a premium plugin and considered the best for this option. The concept is almost the same as in case of Duplicator, but Backupbuddy offers much more besides that.
http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

I recommend you to check both of these plugins in detail (Links are mentioned above) and use that for your purpose of moving websites form localhost to somewhere else.

I hope it helps!

---

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/
- http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I'm a bit busy to try that at the moment but I don't think it is going to work for two reasons. First one is that I wouldn't be able to run the script file produced in the new environment as I don't have access to the command line (the web server is on a NAS I have). And also, I tried a manual method, where everything worked except for some PHP scripts I have (which are created using a shortcode plugin), I don't think any method will work because of that reason, I don't think they will be able to change the URLs in the plugin options for each PHP script

Comment: just FTP the importbuddy.php on new server alongwith the zip package it plugin produce, and run ? 

I would appreciate if you vote up my answer by clicking the Upward arrow button on left side of my answer.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try then, I assumed it was a linux script rather than PHP. Unfortunately I need '15 reputation' to be allowed to upvote, I haven't got 15 yet

Comment: Kindly accept the answer then and do let me know if you need help anymore